# ASP.NET Core 3.0 app deployed to Ubuntu 18.04 throws Could not load file or assembly System.Diagnostics.TraceSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ubuntu-18.04, asp.net-core-3.0

Needless to say the app works locally but it throws this error only when deployed to Ubuntu 18.04.

The app is nothing special, it uses Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table and App Insights. What's more, it worked about 2 weeks ago when it was .Net Core 2.2 but the Linux machine has autoupdate set up. And then one day it just stopped working throwing this:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.TraceSource, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

So I decided to go with ASP.NET Core 3.0 hoping it would fix this Exception. But no, the whole package changes, the error stays!

I tried self-contained, portable, linux-x64... no luck :|

I can't understand where is this package coming from. Stack trace shows that is's coming from Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage. But I do NOT use it in the project ***except*** for the test project!

Stack Trace:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+d__4`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at ShortenerServices.UriStorage+<GetFullUriByShortenedPartAsync>d__1.MoveNext (ShortenerServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullShortenerServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: E:\repos\URLShortener\ShortenerServices\UriStorage.csShortenerServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 36)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at ShortenerServices.ShortenerService+<GetSourceUriByShortenedPartAsync>d__3.MoveNext (ShortenerServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullShortenerServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: E:\repos\URLShortener\ShortenerServices\ShortenerService.csShortenerServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 40)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at URLShortener.Pages.IndexModel+<OnGetAsync>d__1.MoveNext (URLShortener, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullURLShortener, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: E:\repos\URLShortener\URLShortener\Pages\Index.cshtml.csURLShortener, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 30)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod+d__4`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.ExecutorFactory+GenericTaskHandlerMethod+d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker+<InvokeHandlerMethodAsync>d__30.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker+<InvokeNextPageFilterAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker+<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__22.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__23.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker+<InvokeAsync>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<Invoke>d__3.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=2.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware+<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
>   Inner exception System.IO.FileNotFoundException handled at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext:
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
>      at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.ToObject (Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableOperationHttpResponseParsers.ReadSingleItem (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableOperationHttpResponseParsers+d__5.MoveNext (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.Protocol.TableOperationHttpResponseParsers+d__3`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableQuery`1+<>c__DisplayClass24_0`2+<<QueryImpl>b__2>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)
>      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+<ExecuteAsyncInternal>d__4`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35)

### UPDATE - deployed to App Service (Windows)

Obviously, it works without any problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this problem anymore with .Net Core 3.1. So please update your apps.